# CMake how to configure this C++ project?

Tags: c++, cmake

I want a cmake project with two configurations BUILD and TEST.

BUILD compiles all sources not in test subdirectory into a shared library.
TEST compiles all sources, including those in test subdirectory (which includes main.cpp) into an executable that runs the tests. I don't want TEST to build the shared library. I don't want BUILD to build the test executable.

I currently have it on disk as:

```
project/
  test/
    test_foo.cpp
    main.cpp

  bar.hpp
  widget.hpp
  bar.cpp
  widget.cpp
  ...
```

I can move things around if it makes it easier. What do I put in my CMakeLists.txt files?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg He's asking how his CMakeLists.txt would look for the configuration he wants, how is that opinion-based?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to make it clearer what you want, and especially change the title.

Comment: I think Joachim means something like his question aims to much on "do my work". "What do I put in..." is a bad way to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to use cmake's [OPTION](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/option.html) command. Pick one configuration to be on by default (or neither if you want to force the person compiling the code to choose)

```
OPTION( BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY "Compile sources into shared library" ON )
OPTION( RUN_TESTS "Compile test executable and run it" OFF )
```

You'll want to make sure that the options are mutually exclusive, and error out otherwise

```
if ( BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY AND RUN_TESTS )
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Can't build shared library and run tests at same time")
endif()
```

You can then put the rest of your commands inside if blocks based on those variables

```
if ( BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY )
  #add subdirectories except for test, add sources to static library, etc
endif()

if ( RUN_TESTS )
  #compile an executable and run it, etc.
endif()
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get things working based on this example.